# @Formula count on ManyToMany

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to add a like count field on my Song entity, but I keep getting syntax errors as I'm not very proficient in SQL.

My like system works, but I'd like to display the count in the songs view. It should count by how many times the song ID appears in "user_likes_song" table.

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "SELECT"
>         Position: 295

Formula annotation:

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "song")
public class Song {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "serial")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "author", nullable = false)
    private String author;

    @Column(name = "content", nullable = false)
    private String content;

    @Formula("SELECT COUNT(i.id) FROM user_likes_song i WHERE song_id = i.id")
    private long likeCount;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "band_id", nullable = false)
    private Band band;
```

Tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_acc (
      id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      username text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      password text NOT NULL,
      first_name text NULL,
      last_name text NULL,
      age INT NULL,
      phone text NULL,
      email text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
      status active_status NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active',
      create_date TIMESTAMP without TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
      update_date TIMESTAMP without TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL
    );

    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table song
    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS song (
      id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      name text NOT NULL,
      author text NULL,
      content text NOT NULL,
      status song_status NOT NULL DEFAULT 'inactive',
      create_date TIMESTAMP without TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
      update_date TIMESTAMP without TIME ZONE DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
      band_id integer NOT NULL,
      user_id integer NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT fk_song_band
        FOREIGN KEY (band_id)
        REFERENCES band (id)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT fk_song_user1
        FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES user_acc (id)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

    -- -----------------------------------------------------
    -- Table user likes song
    -- -----------------------------------------------------

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_likes_song (
      id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
      user_id integer NOT NULL,
      song_id integer NOT NULL,
      CONSTRAINT fk_user_likes_song_user1
        FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
        REFERENCES user_acc (id)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
      CONSTRAINT fk_user_likes_song_song1
        FOREIGN KEY (song_id)
        REFERENCES song (id)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Edit:

Fixed it by adding parentheses and joining tables together:

```
@Formula("(SELECT COUNT(s.id) FROM user_acc u INNER JOIN user_likes_song us on u.id = us.user_id " +
            "INNER JOIN song s on us.song_id = s.id WHERE us.song_id = s.id )")
    private Long likeCount;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is due to syntax error on hibernate @Formula, so let me explain in depth, when you put a query on the formula, in Hibernate is added a subquery, when finding a song is executed the following query for example:

> SELECT id, name, author, content, 
>   (SELECT COUNT(i.id) FROM user_likes_song i WHERE song_id = i.id) as formula  FROM ....

then you need to add parenthesis **(** **)** in your subquery.

```
@Formula("(SELECT COUNT(i.id) FROM user_likes_song i WHERE song_id = i.id)")
private long likeCount;
```

Comment: Hmm okay, thank you, that got rid of the syntax error, but now I'm getting "ERROR: column song0_.song_id does not exist" :O

Comment: @HeikoPiirme Okay, looks like a new error, so add stacktracer or error message on your question, so I will check it , and help you as well.

Comment: I think song doesn[t have id, then you can count by other way for now, or something is wrong about your records saved

Comment: I can like songs and stuff just fine, I'd just like to have the like count aswell, table structure is in my question. I'll add the error in a second.

Comment: Oh I fixed it, guess I had to use joins to get it working, thanks for the step forward anyways!

Comment: Ok , @HeikoPiirme , kind regards!