# @Formula to count object from a @OneToMany association in spring data jpa

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

In a java rest api, with spring boot, and spring-dta-jpa, db is postgresql
I have a `Book` entity that contains `bookCopies`. These `bookCopies` can be available or not.
I'm trying to retrieve the book with the numbers of copies available.
The books can be searched by title or author name.

I manage to get the info by adding a `@Transient` field in my book entity, with the `@Transient` annotation on a `getNbCopiesAvailable()` method, but I'm asked to do it with `@Formula` annotation, and I can't figure out how to do it.

I'm actually getting an error :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERREUR: plus d'une ligne renvoyée par une sous-requête utilisée comme une expression 
// which means that several lines are sent by the sub-query
```

Here are my entities:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String isbn;
    @NotNull
    private String title;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "book", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<BookCopy> copyList = new ArrayList<>();

    @NotNull
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(name = "book_author",
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "author_id"))
    private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();

    @Formula("(SELECT COUNT(bc.id) FROM book b left join book_copy bc on bc.book_id = b.id  WHERE bc.available = 'true' GROUP BY b.id)")
    private Long nbCopiesAvailable;


@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class BookCopy {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String barcode;
    private String editor;
    private boolean available = true;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Book book;
```

Here is my repository with the query to retrieve books by title and author :

```java
    @Query("select b, a from Book b join b.authors a where b.title like %:title% and concat(a.firstName, ' ', a.lastName) like %:author%")
    List<Book> findByTitleAndAuthor(@Param("title")String title,@Param("author") String author);
```

The 
`@Formula("(SELECT COUNT(bc.id) FROM book b left join book_copy bc on bc.book_id = b.id  WHERE bc.available = 'true' GROUP BY b.id)")`
was hard to write without having syntax errors, and it's strange to me to mix native sql and jpql. But if I try to write the `@Formula` in jpql it doesn't work at all.

I checked this topic that was the closest to my problem ([@Formula count on ManyToMany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55833576/formula-count-on-manytomany)), but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You have a group by on a column not in the select. You don't need the group by as you are only selecting the count.

Comment: *if i try to write the @formula in jpql it doesn't work at all*. Needs to be native SQL for `@Formula`.

Comment: Thank you that's true it works without the group by and the solution selected ! below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to reference the book in the where clause:

```
@Formula("(SELECT COUNT(bc.id) FROM book b " +
         "left join book_copy bc on bc.book_id = b.id " +
         "WHERE bc.available = 'true' " +
         "and b.id = id " + // This is the important condititon
         "GROUP BY b.id)")
private Long nbCopiesAvailable;
```

Otherwise your query is returning all books.